# Iframe responsivo para movil

Tags: html, css, responsive, iframe

Buen día a todos, 
Estoy jalando el contenido de una pagina web en otra mediante Iframe, estoy tratando de hacerlo responsivo para ver la pagina web en el movil, todo bien, pero me sale unos espacios en ambos costados, quisiera quitar esos espacios y que se vea el contenido en todo la pantalla del movil. (ver imagen)

Favor si alguien tiene una idea, favor compartir.

Esta es la pagina para que lo prueben es su movil: http://almendraruiz.com/

[image: Codigo]

```css
.body  {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;  
 background: #000;
}

.panorama {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 180%; /* 500 (height) / 1500 (Width) =0.333=33.333% */
    height: 0;
}
.panorama iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display:block; 
    /*border: 3px solid red;*/
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=euc-jp">
    <!-- COMMON TAGS -->        
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="es"/>    
    <title>Almendra</title>
    <!-- Search Engine -->        
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/movil.css" type="text/css" media="all">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <meta name="author" content="Almendras">
    <meta name="keywords" content="ALMENDRA,Arquitectura,Diseño de Interiores"/>    
    <meta name="image" content="http://almendraruiz.com/Logo.jpg">
    <meta name="description" content="Negocio de Arquitectura, Diseño de Interiores de la Arq. Almendra Ruiz">    
    <meta name="distribution" content="global"/>    
    <meta name="robots" content="Index, Follow, Archive"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://almendraruiz.com/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="http://almendraruiz.com/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://carpetawix.wixsite.com/almendraruiz"/>

    <!-- Open Graph general (Facebook, Pinterest & Google+) -->
    <meta property="og:title" content="ALMENDRA" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://almendraruiz.com" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://almendraruiz.com/Logo.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Arquitectura, Dise単o de Interiores de la Arq. Almendra Ruiz" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Arquitectura, Dise単o de Interiores" />
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="100000306877456"/> 


    
    </head>

<body style="background:black;margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:scroll">
     <div class="panorama" style="display:block;"> 
          <iframe src="https://carpetawix.wixsite.com/almendraruiz" 
                  frameborder="0" border="0" scrolling="si" style="overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:scroll;width:105%;" height="105%" width="100%" allowfullscreen>
          </iframe>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola Alan, he mirado en tu página y no me aparece la imagen como la que muestras en la imagen. ¿Estás seguro de que has subido todos los estilos?

Comment: Hola Francisco un gusto conocerte, en tu celular se ve completo?          
He subido todo el codigo en el CSS que esta publicado al inicio. Quizás no sea mucha la diferencia, pero sería genial si la pagina se viera completo todo el ancho en el movil. Si le falta algun código, favor podrías indicarmelo, saludos

Answer (score 1):

Puedes forzar por CSS que el iframe ocupe el total de la pantalla de este modo:

```
.panorama iframe {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100vw !important;
   height: 100vh !important;
   padding: 0 !important;
   margin: 0 !important;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```